# F# - Treating a function like a map

Tags: dictionary, f#, functional-programming

Long story short, I came up with this funny function **set**, that takes a function, **f : 'k -> 'v**, a chosen value, **k : 'k**, a chosen result, **v : 'v**, uses f as the basis for a new function **g : 'k -> 'v** that is the exact same as **f**, except for that it now holds that, **g k = v**.

Here is the (pretty simple) F# code I wrote in order to make it:

```
let set : ('k -> 'v) -> 'k -> 'v -> 'k -> 'v = 
    fun f k v x ->
        if x = k then v else f x
```

My questions are:

***Does this function pose any problems?***

I could imagine repeat use of the function, like this

```
let kvs : (int * int) List = ... // A very long list of random int pairs.
List.fold (fun f (k,v) -> set f k v) id kvs
```

would start building up a long list of functions on the heap. Is this something to be concerned about?

***Is there a better way to do this, while still keeping the type?***

I mean, I *could* do stuff like construct a type for holding the original function, **f**, a Map, setting key-value pairs to the map, and checking the map first, the function second, when using keys to get values, but that's not what interests me here - what interest me is having a function for "modifying" a single result for a given value, for a given function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potential problems:

1. The `set`-modified function leaks space if you override the same value twice:

   ```
   let huge_object = ...
   let small_object = ...

   let f0 = set f 0 huge_object
   let f1 = set f0 0 small_object
   ```

   Even though it can never be the output of `f1`, `huge_object` cannot be garbage-collected until `f1` can: `huge_object` is referenced by `f0`, which is in turn referenced by the `f1`.
2. The `set`-modified function has overhead linear in the number of `set` operations applied to it.

I don't know if these are *actual* problems for your intended application.

If you wish `set` to have exactly the type `('k -> 'v) -> 'k -> 'v -> 'k -> 'v` then I don't see a better way(*). The obvious idea would be to have a "modification table" of functions you've already modified, then let `set` look up a given `f` in this table. But function types do not admit equality checking, so you cannot compare `f` to the set of functions known to your modification table.

(*) Reflection not withstanding.

Comment: You mention reflection. Could you talk a bit more about how that could be used?

Also, what if the type **'k** is a simple discriminated union?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference `'k` is some known type `t`. You'd then consider functions `(t -> 'v)`, but _no_ function type has equality, so also not this one. (It's a famous result in computer science that it's in general impossible to determine if two functions are equal, i.e., produce the same output for the same input.)

Comment: Wrt. reflection, I imagine you could use reflection to get your hands on the reference to run-time representation of the function `'k -> 'v`. That you _can_ compare for equality, and so put in a map.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the answers. It was very informative. :)